# Interacting with other addins

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using word 2007 Version and came across one problem and looking for a solution to it.

I am using Grammarly Add-in for word and I am looking for a way to accept all the suggestions that Grammarly add-ins provide. I try to record a macro so that I can have some insight into the possible solution. But the macro recorder does not record anything while working within that add in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best what you could do is to contact Grammarly add-in developers to provide any public interface implemented in the COM add-in and which can be consumed by third-parties. The following walkthrough demonstrates how to expose an object in a VSTO Add-in to other Microsoft Office solutions, including Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) and COM VSTO Add-ins - [Walkthrough: Call code in a VSTO Add-in from VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2022).